# Confused about GNU `sort(1)` of a numerical sub field

Tags: sorting, command-line, command, gnu, gnu-sort

I wish to sort a space separated `table`, with the numerical value that found on the 2nd field. I can assume that the 2nd field is always fooN but the length of N is unknown:

```
antiq. foo11 girls
colleaguing foo2 Leinsdorf
Cousy foo0 Montgomeryville
bowlegged foo1 pollack
Chevrier foo10 ill-conceived
candlebomb foo3 seventieths
autochthony foo101 re-enable
beneficiate foo100 osteometric
```

I read `man sort(1)` and played with all sort of options. On my system I found the line:

```
sort -n -k2.5 table
```

to work.

My question is **why?**

According to the man page:

```
-k, --key=POS1[,POS2]
   start a key at POS1, end it at POS 2 (origin 1) 
...
POS is F[.C][OPTS], where F is the field number and C the characterposition in the
field. OPTS is one or more single-letter ordering options, which override global
ordering options for that key. If no key is given, use the entire line as the key.
```

So why `sort -n -k2.4` table don't work and `sort -n -k2.5` does?

Comment: By `sort -n -k.5` do you mean `sort -n -k2.5`?

Comment: @dalle, Yes, you are correct. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: **the leading space(s) are counted as part of the field**, unless:

```
sort -b -n -k2.4 table
```

or curiously:

```
LC_ALL=C sort -t" " -n -k2.4 table
```

that also yields the correct result.

---

... and one more thing ...

It seem that it is better to use:

```
sort -b -n -k2.4,2 table
```

and thus limit the sort to the end of the 2nd field.

Comment: Great findings. Let me add: If, alternatively, you add the `[-]n` option directly to the field index (as is needed if you have multiple keys with different sort logic), you also have to put the `[-]b` option there; thus, the equivalent of your 1st command is: `sort -k2.4bn,2 table`.

Comment: Re 2nd command: I think the 'LC_ALL=C' part is unnecessary. The command works (assuming *1* space each between fields), because `sort` - unlike in the default case - does NOT consider the preceding separator part of the field whenever `-t` is specified (even if the argument is a space). There is another, more subtle difference, however: by default, multiple adjacent blanks are treated as a single separator; with `-t`, they're not - multiple adjacent ones count as empty fields and the field index must be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: Re 3rd command: great point - the unexpected default is to include the remainder of the *entire line* in the key.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it helps but [info sort](http://www.phpman.info/index.php/info/sort) states the following:

> sort -t : -k 2,2n -k 5.3,5.4
>
> ```
>  Note that if you had written `-k 2' instead of `-k 2,2' `sort'
>  would have used all characters beginning in the second field and
>  extending to the end of the line as the primary _numeric_ key.
>  For the large majority of applications, treating keys spanning
>  more than one field as numeric will not do what you expect.
> ```

Perhaps try adding a space between `-k` and `2`, or try setting `POS2`?